# About my JavaScript Code Function

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/MrBigglesWorth/Lwxoeyyp/408/

This code is suppose to save the checkboxs I've ticked after clicking the Save button. Currently that is working but only for one Button. I'm trying to get it to work on all of them to allow me to check them all and save and I plan on adding more than 9 buttons.

Trying to pass through ID's through a function. Not sure how to do it though.

when I click save on it with more than one of the boxs checked, it only keeps the first one checked cause that has the ID box1  is what the javascript is calling in the function. What Code do I need and how do I go about using this function for each btn. I was thinking of a onclick with .this might work but I am not sure.

```js
function save() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('btn1');
  localStorage.setItem('btn1', checkbox.checked);
}

function load() {
  var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('btn1'));
  document.getElementById("btn1").checked = checked;
}

function wis() {
  location.reload();
  localStorage.clear()

}

load();
```

```html
<h1>Project Name</h1>
<h2>Link To Site</h2>
<div class="navbar">
  <center>
    <input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="Save" onclick="save()" />
    <input type="button" id="resetBtn" value="Reset" onclick="wis()" />
  </center>
</div>

<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn1" />
    <label for="btn1">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn2" />
    <label for="btn2">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn3" />
    <label for="btn3">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn4" />
    <label for="btn4">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn5" />
    <label for="btn5">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn6" />
    <label for="btn6">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn7" />
    <label for="btn7">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn8" />
    <label for="btn8">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>


</form>
```

Comment: use class insted of id for targeting multiple items at a time..

Comment: Snippet here gives localstorage error but so does your jsfiddle

Comment: sorry, I forgot the script.

Comment: I'm not trying to target multiple at a time. I'm trying to figure out how to pass through an ID through a function that currently setup only for one ID.

Comment: here is somthing http://jsfiddle.net/Lwxoeyyp/409/

Comment: or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/h7x94s40/1/

Comment: Ty! The Code worked. If you guys return at all. If you could explain this code.

Comment: @Jared please check i have added a sample :D

Answer (score 0):

here is something i tried hope it helps...
[Note : i have used your code only to make it simple if you still have anything to ask please comment.]
here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lwxoeyyp/411/
HTML :

```
 <h1>Project Name</h1>
<h2>Link To Site</h2>
<div class="navbar">
  <center>
    <input type="button" id="saveBtn" value="Save" onclick="save()"/>
     <input type="button" id="loadBtn" value="Load values" onclick="load()"/>
    <input type="button" id="resetBtn" value="Reset" onclick="resetValues()"/>
    <input type="button" id="resetBtn1" value="Reset Local" onclick="resetLocal()"/>
  </center>
</div>

<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn1" class="test" />
    <label for="btn1">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn2" class="test" />
    <label for="btn2">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn3" class="test" />
    <label for="btn3">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn4" class="test" />
    <label for="btn4">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn5" class="test" />
    <label for="btn5">Wordpress Installed</label>
  </p>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
// save data to localstorage
function save(){
   // get all the checkboxes at a time.
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
   // iterate to collection of checkboxes object and save its id value in localstorage.
   for(var i =0 ;i<checkbox.length;i++){
      var id = checkbox[i].id;
      localStorage.setItem(id, checkbox[i].checked);
    }    
 }

// load the data from localstorage.
function load(){    
  // iterate to collection of checkboxes object and getits id value
  var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  for(var i =0 ;i<checkbox.length;i++){
    var id = checkbox[i].id;
     // see here used string comparison as value returned from localstorage is string.
      if(localStorage.getItem(id) === 'true'){
         checkbox[i].checked = true;
       }
     else
     {
         checkbox[i].checked = false;
     }
   }
}



// reset values of all checkboxes
    function resetValues(){
       var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
       for(var i =0 ;i<checkbox.length;i++){
         var item = document.getElementById(checkbox[i].id);
           if(item.checked == true){
             item.checked = false;
           }
       }    
    }   
    // remove data from localstorage.
    function resetLocal(){
      localStorage.clear();
      alert('localstorage cleared');
    }
```